# What software should I use to run a simple API request on Windows?

Tags: api, command-line

I want to run this API request on Win10:

```
curl 'https://api.co2signal.com/v1/latest?countryCode=DK' -H 'auth-token: 2905e4afe4a7eb88'
```

I tried to run in in Command Prompt, Git Bash, Postman, but I always have this error:

> "message": "No API key found in headers or querystring"

What am I doing wrongly? My friend ran it successfully in Terminal on a Mac.

Original web page with the code: https://docs.co2signal.com/#introduction

Sorry if I wrote something wrong, I'm a beginner in this topic.

Comment: This question is off-topic here (please read [ask]), but would be on-topic on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip the command line on a Windows machine, and just use `Postman`

Can do all of what `curl` does with a nice GUI front end.

Comment: I upvoted you on the general principle that I love Postman; however, the OP explicitly states that Postman does not work for him in Windows (which sounds very strange to me). In any case, the question is badly off-topic here